# How do you change a QGraphicsScene from another function?

Tags: c++, qt, qgraphicsview, qgraphicsscene

My program has a QGraphicsView called `SimulatorGV` and it has a QGraphicsScene called `Simulation`. In the main function I have drawn a few rectangles and ellipses. I want to be able to draw on the same scene in another function too.

**In essence, how do you add shapes to a scene from another function?** *(Which is called when a button on the user interface is pressed)*

---

So far I've tried to pass the QGraphicsView to the other function? Below is the main ui function (irrelevant statements cut out):

```
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    Simulation = new QGraphicsScene(this);


        ui->SimulatorGV->setScene(Simulation);

        Simulation->addRect(0,415,20,50,noPen,greyBrush); 
        Simulation->addRect(425,230,10,420,noPen,goldBrush); 
        Simulation->addEllipse(80,90,700,700,greyPen,noBrush); 
        Simulation->addRect(72,215,90,450,noPen,blackBrush); 

}
```

---

In the header file I declared this function in the private slots:

```
void DrawingSimulation(QGraphicsView *SimulationGV);
```

**Should it be like this instead?**

```
void DrawingSimulation(QGraphicsScene *Simulation);
```

I called the function in another function like this:

```
DrawingSimulation(ui->SimulatorGV);
```

**Should it be like this instead?**

```
DrawingSimulation(ui->SimulatorGV->Simulation);
```

**or?**

```
DrawingSimulation(ui->Simulation);
```

---

This is the function I want to be able to draw on the scene from:

```
void RASP::DrawingSimulation(QGraphicsView *SimulationGV)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < DisplayAlphaParticleNumber; i++)
    {
        if (ParticleLocation[i*6+3] != 0 || ParticleLocation[i*6+6] != 0) 
        {
            ui->SimulatorGV->setScene(Simulation);
            Simulation->addEllipse(ParticleLocation[i*6+3],ParticleLocation[i*6+4],10,10);
        }
    }
}
```

*`SimulatorGV` is the name of the QGraphicsView in my ui form. `RASP` is the name of the project. `ParticleLocation[i*6+3]` is the x coordinate and `[i*6+4]` is the y coordinate.*

**Was I right to pass the QGraphicsView onto the varibale instead of the QGraphicsScene `Simulation`?**

**Did I pass it correctly?**

**In the DrawingSimulation function did I add the ellipse correctly?**

Edit: 
**In essence, how do you add shapes to a scene from another function?** *(Which is called when a button on the user interface is pressed)*

When a button is pressed this function is called:

```
    void RASP::on_Button1_clicked()
    {
    //some values set
    //some other functions called then the main one that leads to the drawingsimulation   

     mainfunction();
    }
```

Then inside the `mainfunction():`

```
void RASP::mainfunction()
{
     DrawingSimulation(); //is called
}
```

Now the function `DrawingSimulation()` which I would like to draw on the original scene in the `RASP::RASP()`  (MyClass::MyClass) is called.

---

My previous attempt was to have a boolean function that is set true by the button then the addEllipse:

```
MyClass::MyClass()
{
ui->setupUi(this);
        Simulation = new QGraphicsScene(this);


            ui->SimulatorGV->setScene(Simulation);

            Simulation->addRect(0,415,20,50,noPen,greyBrush); 
            Simulation->addRect(425,230,10,420,noPen,goldBrush); 
            Simulation->addEllipse(80,90,700,700,greyPen,noBrush); 
            Simulation->addRect(72,215,90,450,noPen,blackBrush); 

if (SimulationRun == true)
{
for (int i = 0; i < DisplayAlphaParticleNumber; i++)
        {
            if (ParticleLocation[i*6+3] != 0 || ParticleLocation[i*6+6] != 0) 
            {
                ui->SimulatorGV->setScene(Simulation);
                Simulation->addEllipse(ParticleLocation[i*6+3],ParticleLocation[i*6+4],10,10);
            }
        }
}
}
```

and then in the button clicked function setting SimulationRun = to true.

Comment: This is becoming messy. I feel like your problem is actually to know how to call functions and pass parameters in C++....no real specific problem with the `QGraphicsScene` class. Please learn some C++ basic before trying to do complex stuff as you are trying to.

Comment: @jpo38 My main problem is that I didn't use signals & slots. I think I can solve this problem using it thanks to your post. I'm a student who has been a bit ambitious with a school project but you're answer has definitely been helpful, thank you very much :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's keep it simple.

If you have:

```
MyClass::MyClass() : ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    Simulation = new QGraphicsScene(this);

    ui->SimulatorGV->setScene(Simulation);

    Simulation->addRect(0,415,20,50,noPen,greyBrush); 
    Simulation->addRect(425,230,10,420,noPen,goldBrush); 
    Simulation->addEllipse(80,90,700,700,greyPen,noBrush); 
    Simulation->addRect(72,215,90,450,noPen,blackBrush); 
}
```

If this works, then, this will work too:

```
MyClass::MyClass() : ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    Simulation = new QGraphicsScene(this); // supposing MyClass has a Simulation attribute of type QGraphicsScene

    ui->SimulatorGV->setScene(Simulation);

    addItems(); // calling function below
}

void MyClass::addItems()
{
    // declared "void addItems();" in header file
    addItems( Simulation ); // calling function below that could be static
}

void MyClass::addItems( QGraphicsScene* simu )
{
    // declared "static void addItems(QGraphicsScene* simu);" in header file
    simu->addRect(0,415,20,50,noPen,greyBrush); 
    simu->addRect(425,230,10,420,noPen,goldBrush); 
    simu->addEllipse(80,90,700,700,greyPen,noBrush); 
    simu->addRect(72,215,90,450,noPen,blackBrush); 
}
```

Then, if this works, you now know how to modify the secene from "another function".

Finally, you should also have:

```
void MyClass::DrawingSimulation()
{
    // declared "void DrawingSimulation();" in header file
    DrawingSimulation( Simulation );
}

void MyClass::DrawingSimulation(QGraphicsScene *simu)
{
    // declared "void DrawingSimulation(QGraphicsScene *simu);" in header file
    for (int i = 0; i < DisplayAlphaParticleNumber; i++)
    {
        if (ParticleLocation[i*6+3] != 0 || ParticleLocation[i*6+6] != 0) 
        {
            simu->addEllipse(ParticleLocation[i*6+3],ParticleLocation[i*6+4],10,10);
        }
    }
}
```

**Note that `DrawingSimulation()` could also be a `slot`** (declare it using `public slots:` in your header file. Then, if you `connect` it to the `clicked()` `signal` of a `QPushButton` of your GUI (for instance), it will be called when the button is clicked and ellipse will be added.

Like this:

```
MyClass::MyClass()
{
    ...

    connect( ui->pushButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(DrawingSimulation()) );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply :D You're method is greater. it's my mistake for not mentioning in the question that the other function is called when a button in my user interface is pressed (actually it is called by another function that is called when a button is pressed). I've added the code for the button being pressed in the main question at the end. Could you explain how I could call the "add items" function when a button is pressed? I've also included my attempt at doing this.

Comment: Updated my post, please have a look.

Comment: Hey, I've been trying to implement your above suggestion (the second code block) and have two questions: what do you mean by `ui = new ....;`? and how did you declare the function in the header file? Because when you do use `addItems()` the program outputs the error "function does not take 0 arguements" when I declare as `void addItems(QGraphicsScene *scene);`  and says "overload member function not found" or when declared as  `void addItems();` "function does not take 1 arguments". I've tried your example a new project just to test it out and will include the full code in an edit. Thanks :)

Comment: Both `addItems` function must be declared in header file. `ui = new ...` was just to mention `ui` object creation. Updated my post to clarify all that.